# rails s gives "connect to localhost failed" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, command-prompt

I get an error when I run "rails s" on my command line. This is the following error I get:

> WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.3, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
>
> => Booting WEBrick
>
> => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on `http://0.0.0.0:3000`
>
> => Call with -d to detach
>
> => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>
> Connecting to stomp://localhost:61613 as
>
> connect to localhost failed: Connection refused - connect(2) will retry(#0) in 5

any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using some Message Queue system that uses stomp protocol. That server should be started before you start your rails app.